# slick: How to map nested case class into multiple database tables

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have one question regarding the document and example from "http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/userdefined.html#combining-mapped-types".

The user mapped case classes are nested, but the "shape_c" table is flatten? I mean table shape_c contains four columns (p1, p2, id, s) instead of two(id, s)? How can I insert the nested case classes into both table of shape_c(id,s) and shape_b(p1,p2)?

Or we can only insert into one single table(flattened)?

Thanks,